# Какой словообразующий суффикс в слове ЧИТАЙ?

Tags: словообразование, суффиксы

В слове ЧИТАЙ какой словообразующий суффикс - АЙ или А? И что тогда такое Й?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чит/ай-словообр. суфф./+ нул. формообр. суфф.+ нулевое оконч.

а//ай - чередование в суффиксе.

Answer (score 2):

Повелительное наклонение глагола образуется от основы настоящего/будущего времени при помощи суффикса -И- или т.н. нулевого суффикса (выражает значение повелительного наклонения) и нулевого окончания (выражает значения 2 л. ед.ч.):

идти: ИД-ут --- ИД-+И+0,
 читать: ЧИТА/й-у/т ---> ЧИТАй-+-0-+-0.

По этому типу образуются формы повелительного наклонения от многих других глаголов:

МЕЧТАТЬ: МЕЧТА/Й-У/т ---> МЕЧТАЙ-0-0, РАБОТАТЬ: РАБОТА/Й-У/т ---> РАБОТАЙ-0-0 и др.

В основе инфинитива --- суффикс -А-, а в основе настоящего времени этих глаголов --- один  суффикс: граф. -а-, фонет. /-ай-/. Соотношение между глагольными основами инфинитива и настоящего времени  -А- / -АЙ- создает продуктивный тип, по образцу которого строится система образования грамматических форм у вновь образующихся глаголов. Так, по этому типу появилась система грамматических  форм от глаголов СЛЕСАРНИЧАТЬ --- СЛЕСАРНИЧАЮТ, ОРОШАТЬ --- ОРОШАЮТ, ПРИОБЩАТЬ --- ПРИОБЩАЮТ и др.